# Android Fragment Manager Null Object Reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void switchView() {
    //sync the BottomBar Icons since a different Thread is running
    Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    refresh.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((MainActivity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, mapFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

When i run this code everything is fine, but when i add the line

```
mapFragment.setUrl("www.examplestuff.com");
```

the app crashes with *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference*

My Fragment class looks like this

```
public WebView mapView;
private String thisURL;

public void setUrl(String url) {
    thisURL = url;
    mapView.loadUrl(thisURL);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container, false);

    mapView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    this.setUrl("file:///android_asset/www/MapView.html");

    mapView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = mapView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //allow cross origin - like jsonP
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    return view;
}
```

Also call there the method `this.setURL()` and works fine.

What I am doing wrong?
Has the FragmentManager no access of the instance WebView of the fragment???

Comment: did you put fragment statically in your xml (you cant)? Show xml where is your fragment..

Comment: No just the WebView is in the xml of the fragment - but the fragment itself is not statically in any layout xml. The method I need is visible and accessable at my point of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This be because when you call `setUrl` it invokes this method:

```
public void setUrl(String url) {
    thisURL = url;
    mapView.loadUrl(thisURL);
}
```

the line `mapView.loadUrl(thisURL);` accesses the `mapView`. However you are likely calling `setUrl` before the Android system has called `onCreateView`, therefore `mapView` is null, causing said crash.

```
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        thisURL = url;
        if(mapView != null) {
            mapView.loadUrl(thisURL);
        } 
    }
```

and

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container, false);

     mapView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
     if(thisUrl != null) {
        mapView.loadUrl(thisURL);
     }
     ... other code
```

Then `mapFragment.setUrl("www.examplestuff.com");` would work

---

A better solution would be to understand more the Activity & Fragment lifecycles and not call `setUrl` when the `Fragment` is in an invalid state :-) You are probably calling `setUrl` when really you should be passing the Url as an intent extra when the fragment is created. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thx Dude. Works fine. And i look for the lifecycles :)